# Access Denied Federated Users Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I am getting an access denied whenever I try to access amazon s3 through my .NET application. I have an IAM user and if I use his credentials it works fine. But if I create a federated user using his credentials the resulting user cannot access buckets in Amazon s3. One thing to notice is that I am not specifying a policy for my federated user in my code. I want him to have the same access level as the IAM user. But if I specify a value for policy in my code I can access  and List buckets.
Any pointers ?

```
  private static SessionAWSCredentials GetTemporaryFederatedCredentials(
                                string accessKeyId, string secretAccessKeyId)
        {
            var config = new AmazonSecurityTokenServiceConfig();
            var stsClient = 
                new AmazonSecurityTokenServiceClient(
                                             accessKeyId, secretAccessKeyId, config);
            var federationTokenRequest =
                                     new GetFederationTokenRequest();
            federationTokenRequest.Name = "User1";
//            federationTokenRequest.Policy =
//                @"{
//                              ""Statement"":
//                              [
//                                {
//                                  ""Action"":[""s3:ListAllMyBuckets""],
//                                  ""Effect"":""Allow"",
//                                  ""Resource"":""arn:aws:s3:::*""
//                                                }
//                                              ]
//                                            }";
            federationTokenRequest.DurationSeconds = 3600; 
         GetFederationTokenResponse federationTokenResponse = 
                         stsClient.GetFederationToken(federationTokenRequest);
            GetFederationTokenResult federationTokenResult = 
                             federationTokenResponse.GetFederationTokenResult;
            Credentials credentials = federationTokenResult.Credentials;


            var sessionCredentials =
                new SessionAWSCredentials(credentials.AccessKeyId,
                                          credentials.SecretAccessKey,
                                          credentials.SessionToken);
            return sessionCredentials;
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Federated identities work using roles.  Have you given permission to the role or added the role to the bucket policy?

Comment: @Abhi.Net did you get solution to this? I am also stuck here.